# Problems downloading JPEG from the Internet

Tags: android, url

I am using the following class to download an image. The URL I am sending is correct but url.getContext()  returns null every time. Does anybody know why?

```
package com.WasserSportLotse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


class ImageDownloader {
    private Drawable d;

    public ImageDownloader(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Drawable getImage(){
        return d;
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {

        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked back at this and realized I was I was upcasting an input stream into an Object. What the hell. I was still in my internship I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the class quite a bit and found a much simpler version

```
    private String path = "http://www.*YOURPATH.COM/SOMETHING*";
    private String file;
    private String url;

    public ImageDownloader(String file){
        this.file = URLEncoder.encode(file);
        url = path + this.file;

    }

    public Drawable getImage() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

calling `url.getContent()` will return an image if applicable and only a stream of it's not an image or an audio clip. Though that doesn't seem to be your problem now, it will be a problem once you figure this one out.

Your code looks right. The only thing I can think of is the address isn't built right. It may work in a browser, but the URL class may be more picky than your browser. Make sure you're using the full form URL, with prepending http:// (not just www)

Comment: the address is correct I get this from a JSON object stored on a webserver. I can see the image when I enter the address in my browser

Comment: I'd say try and extend your code so that you have an easier time seeing where the problem is. Use this constructor: `URL(String protocol, String host, String file)` and call `URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()` followed by `connection.getContent()`. All of what you're doing is equivalent to this, but hopefully taking the long road may show you where the problem is.

Comment: If none of that works, I'd just take a different route. Try using `HttpGet`.

Comment: The URL string that I receive from the JSon object have the file included so It doesn't make sense to chop that up just to let the http rebuild it. I can run the url.openConnection() tho. The url shows that the path is /media/images/uploads/Mühlendammschleuse.jpg and the file is /media/images/uploads/Mühlendammschleuse.jpg. Should the file just be Mühlendammschleuse.jpg?

Comment: "ü"

That may be the problem...special character in the filename. You need to URL encode that. Put this in your `fetch(...)` method:

`address = address.replace("ü", "%C3%BC");`

Comment: Also look at this class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Still no joy even with changing the address.